# Laravel 5 custom validation if a file was not uploaded

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I am trying to create a custom validation to check if a file was uploaded in a form.

I looked at the custom errors docs but couldn't make it work.

I found this tutorial: [Custom Error](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-create-custom-validation-rule-exampleexample.html)

In my controller I do this:

```
if($request->hasFile('file'))
        $has_file = 1;
    else
        $has_file = 0;

 $this->validate($request, ['file' => 'isuploaded']);
```

In App/ServiceProvider I added this:

```
Validator::extend('isuploaded', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        return ?;
    });
```

What should I return here? How do I send the $has_file to the validator?

Answer (score 1):

If the `file` field is required the `validate` will check it for you.

Assuming that your form file input has `name="file"`, just:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'file' => 'required
]);
```

In this way if there is no file the validation will fail.

If this is not your case and you want to create the custom rules in `Validator::extend` you should write your own business logic to check if the file exists and just return `true/false`.

Comment: I tried, 'file' => 'required' but it does not do anything if I don't upload a file

Comment: Make sure that your input field is named `file` otherwise you need to edit the `validate` method to match your own